# How do I show menu list with a hamburger icon?

Tags: html, css

My menu is always shown regardless of whether or not the checkbox is ticked. How do I hide it when it's not ticked and show it when it is ticked?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some clean code for what you want to do. (Author : mutedblues)
By the way, watch out for `ul` > `div` > `li` structures.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">CSS Nav</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



By https://codepen.io/mutedblues/pen/MmPNPG
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it, is using of `:checked` on `checkbox` in your CSS/SCSS.

Example:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox1" />
  <div className='navigation__background'>stuff</div>
</div>
```

SCSS/CSS

```
.navigation__background: {
  display: none
}
.checkbox1:checked ~ .navigation__background {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML:

`<input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">`

JavaScript:

```
function toggleMenu(element) {
    element.checked ? openMenu() : closeMenu();
}
```

Use JavaScript to change the CSS.